# How to write an OpenCL function

Tags: function, pointers, reference, opencl

I'm new to OpenCL and I'm trying to implement a simple function in OpenCL. The function is supposed to be called from a kernel function.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int *temp = a;
    b = a;
    a = temp;
}
```

However upon calling it, the swap doesn't work.

Is there a way to pass parameters by reference?

Comment: You're not swapping anything in your function though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have written the function, it is not doing anything. You are just assigning the pointers around. You need to have this:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Reference parameters are not allowed, as far as I recall.

Comment: surely you mean `*a=*b; *b=temp;`